# A Second Geodesic Equation?

Tags: general-relativity, momentum, velocity, geodesics

I have a question about the geodesic equations. I understand the following formulation of it:

$$\frac{d p^\mu}{d\tau} = - \Gamma^j_{v\mu}p^vp^\mu.$$

However, I was reading https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.0037?context=astro-ph and found that it adds a second equation:

$$\frac{d x^\mu}{d\tau} = p^\mu.$$

I do not understand where this second equation comes from. It seems that $\frac{d x^\mu}{d\tau} = u^\mu \neq p^\mu.$ (Where $u^\mu$ is the four velocity.)

Could someone explain this second equation?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren’t the equations in the paper. Equations (5) and (6) take the derivatives with respect to an affine parameter $\lambda$, not the proper time $\tau$. The paper seems to be assuming $\lambda=\tau/m$ in order to make $m$ disappear.

Comment: Thank you so much! That answers my question. :)